# Getting multiple wx widget values with Event Handling

Tags: python, wxpython

CODE: http://pastebin.com/W4uXmazw

I would like to memorize how to get values from any wx widget with event handling after clicking a wx.Button.

In my program i have two fields, the new filename and the contents.

What are the steps i have to take in order to get the values from each field?

From there, i can use pythons f.open and f.write methods to complete my application.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get value of a widget, then you need to make that widget accessible throughout the entire class. To do that, you need to make the variable for the widget into an instance variable. So instead of adding the text control directly to the sizer, you'll want to do something like this:

```
self.newfilename = wx.TextCtrl(panel,-1), 0, wx.TOP, 5)
self.contents = wx.TextCtrl(panel,-1,size=(390,150),style = wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.TE_PROCESS_TAB)
```

Then in your button's event handler, you can just do something like this:

```
valueOne = self.newfilename.GetValue()
contents = self.contents.GetValue()
```

The other way to do it would be to use your panel. If you use "self.panel", then you could grab all its children via its GetChildren method and then iterate over the list and use Python's "isinstance" builtin to check what kind of widget you're accessing. If you have set the widget's name, you can check that too.

Comment: i taught myself today and i really suprised myself, i looked at your answer just now and it is exactly the same with what i was thinking, thanks heaps :)